echo command not working when used inside find block
I have this in my linux script:
find . -name '*.xml' | while read MYXMLFILE; do 

  echo "Checking $MYXMLFILE"

  sleep .5

  ....
  ....

  fi

done

But I see that echo doesn't do anything even though there are many .xml files at the location.
What is wrong here?

Syntax.  You seem to have an extra fi in there.

Always paste your script into https://shellcheck.net, a syntax checker, or install shellcheck locally. Make using shellcheck part of your development process.

I guess the fi at the end is just a leftover from the redaction of the script? Can you post the whole script as well as the command you're using to run it?

(aside from the incomplete if ... fi already noted) I don't see anything wrong except that you might want to change while read to while IFS= read -r to avoid issues with filenames with leading/trailing whitespace and/or backslash characters (or better still use find ... -print0 and while IFS= read -r -d '' to also handle filenames with newlines). In general you should also avoid ALLCAPS for your non-environment variables. But none of these things would cause echo "Checking $MYXMLFILE" to not do anything.

If you want things to work with xml files with special characters, for example spaces like file 1.xml, you can make a find command with -exec like
find -name '*.xml' -exec echo "Checking '{}'" \; -exec cat {} \;

where {} is a placeholder for the file names found by find, and it can manage file names with special characters.
If you have no file names with special characters, the answer by DTdev using a for command might work well.
Edit: If you want to do something more complicated, you can make a separate shellscript that is called via -exec with the file names as parameter, for example
find -name '*.xml' -exec ./doer-script {} \;


Try following:
  for MYXMLFILE in `find . -name '*.xml'`; do 
  echo "Checking $MYXMLFILE"    
  sleep .5
  ....
  ....
done


This is actually more fragile than the OP's while loop - see for example Why is looping over find's output bad practice?
